# Properties of integration with a degree 2 polynomial

Tags: integration

In my textbook, there is a true/false question:

$
\int_{-5}^{5}(ax^2+bx+c)dx = 2\int_{0}^{5}(ax^2+c)dx
$

Solving this particular case I found
both sides to equal:
$
\frac{250a}{3} +10c
$

I recognize this as the property of integrating an even function from -a to a, but I'm not sure about what happens to the middle term bx.

Comment: The integral of the odd part dies. So we don't need to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also know that the integral of an odd function over a domain symmetric about $0$ has to be $0$?

Comment: Ah, yes I see. Thank you.